# Deep copy - choosing the properties to copy

Tags: c#, .net-core, deep-copy

I would like to do a deep copy of an object. This object has some normal string, int, properties but it would also have custom objects (e.g. a list of custom objects).

Is there a way to do a deep copy where I pick and choose which properties to copy?
e.g. I want to copy

```
public class BankAccount
{
  [Required]
  [DeepCopy]
  public string Number { get; }

  [Required]
  [DeepCopy]
  public string Owner { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [DeepCopy]
  public decimal Balance { get; }

  [Required]
  [DeepCopy]
  public List<CustomAddress> {get; set;}

  [Required]
  public List<CustomLinkedAccounts> {get; set;}
}
```

Where perhaps I would want to copy everything except the List of CustomLinkedAccounts.

Comment: Any chance you're just reinventing Automapper? If not, is there anything wrong with requiring that a class implement a `DeepCopy` method that lays down the logic of which properties to deep copy, instead of needing to tag it with attributes? In both cases the logic would be contained in the class itself, after all.

Comment: there is a simplere approach... user newtonsoft json to serializae and deserialize into a new instance.... then you can use [JsonIgnore] to exclude what you want

Comment: @JeroenMostert - would I use automapper and then .ignore to not copy stuff? The plan is to make this generic as there are many classes to come.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro - I will try that now. I haven't used JsonIgnore before.

Comment: The point would be that if you are specifying which properties to copy and not copy, there's nothing generic about it, and each class effectively has its own logic for the copy anyway, so that using a bunch of attributes would not be superior to writing a method. If you made it even more general, along the lines of "copy everything except collections of type `CustomLinkedAccounts` (or some other rule, like "except classes marked with `RelationalTypeAttribute`"), then you'd have something potentially worth implementing differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution I have used in the past for deep cloning.

It requires Newtonsoft JSON library.

It can be adapted to use System.Text.Json if you can't use third party libraries.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class BankAccount
{
  [Required]
  public string Number { get; }

  [Required]
  public string Owner { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public decimal Balance { get; }

  [Required]
  public List<CustomAddress> {get; set;}

  [Required]
  [JsonIgnore]//this is not in the json
  public List<CustomLinkedAccounts> {get; set;}

  public BankAccount Clone()
  {
      var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
      var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BankAccount>(json);

      //this is a deep copy... no reference issues
      return result;
  }
}
```